# Oracle Apex: Aggregate show as top row

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Currently I use interactive report of Oracle Apex

```
    Column1    Column2
A1     1          2
A2     2          3
A3     3          4
A4     4          5
----------------------
       10         14
```

After showing data, I do some calculation such as sum Column1, Column2 using **aggregate function SUM** of interactive report

But the result show as the **last row of report** so I have to **scroll to see the result**.

How can I show the result as the **first row** of report?

```
    Column1    Column2
       10         14
----------------------
A1     1          2
A2     2          3
A3     3          4
A4     4          5
```

Comment: Hi, can i ask if the sum is part of the row of the report?and how did you do it in apex 5?thanks

Comment: Click on Action > Format > Aggregate. After that choose sum and column to sum

Comment: do you know how to use javascript? I got a solution for you if you do

Comment: @vance: Yes, I can use javascript. How about your solution?

Comment: Sorry @kenNguyen, I thought its working. I added a null row at the top of the report then put the total on that top row through DOM manipulation. Its working at first but now its all messed up! That top row I just added is now on the bottom row :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using JavaScript/jQuery (of course this is only one of many ways this can be done, but it works).

The SQL statement that is used to create the report along with all the filter and search information is stored in
 WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET tables

Create a database package to generate that SQL and sum the columns that you want from that and return as XML.

Call that database package from a jQuery AJAX call then parse the XML and using jQuery add a row to the top (and bottom if you like) of the worksheet table and place the results there.

The JavaScript/jQuery function should be called from an after refresh dynamic action for the worksheet in question.

```
function htmldbIRTotals(worksheet,columnList) {
    sessionId   = $("#pInstance").val();
    worksheetId = $(worksheet.triggeringElement).find(".a-IRR-table:last").attr("id");
    baseReportId=parseInt("0"+$("#"+worksheetId+"_rpt_saved_reports").val());

    u="'||pkg||'.getTotals?p_worksheet_id="+worksheetId+"&p_base_Report_Id="+baseReportId+"&p_session_id="+sessionId+"&p_columns="+columnList;

    $.post(u,function(data) {
        var xml = $.parseXML(data);
    });
```

With sessionId, worksheetId, and baseReportId you can retrieve all the info you need

columnList is a colon separated list of the columns that you want to total

You could even get more fancy and add different agregates (i.e. AVG, MIN, MAX etc.)

Example of this at the link below.

http://apps.htmldb.com/apps/f?p=htmldb:knowledgebase:::NO:RP:P5_ID:84315

Comment: Something missing in this sentence: _The JavaScript/jQuery function should be called from an after refresh dynamic action for the worksheet in question._

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the totals may or may not be rendered on the page depending on the page size and the number of records in the result set - so with an Interactive Report, unless you force it to always show All Records, the page might not even be able to use JS tricks to move the summary line to the top.

My preference in this sort of situation is to add a separate region to the page based on a simple SQL query. It will be shown above the interactive report. Unfortunately the columns won't be aligned, however.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

1. Add sub query to calculate the sum
2. Union with existed result
3. Use highlight function to make up the new row

Comment: can you be more explicit? how did you the union? just updated the query? What do you mean by "highlight function"? Can you add a picture to see how it looks?